# Hello World js file not running in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I've added a new page to a sub-site.

Added a content editor web-part.

Then added the following D3 javascipt hello world script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="description" content="D3byEX 1.1"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
      d3.select('body')
        .append('h1')
        .text('Hello World!');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also tried this:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
  d3.select('body')
    .append('h1')
    .text('Hello World!');
</script>
```

The page is blank - why is this and what do I need to do to get Hello World?

---

progress so far

From here I've downloaded the zip "d3.zip": https://d3js.org/
Then I've unzipped the contents into a vanilla document library here:

```
http://SPaddress/testingSubSite/D3docLib/
```

Now I've amended the code in the content editor, and tried each of the following  -they all produce a blank page:

```
<script src="http://SPaddress/testingSubSite/D3docLib/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
     d3.select('body')
       .append('h1')
       .text('Hello World!');
</script>


<script src="http://SPaddress/testingSubSite/D3docLib/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
     d3.select('body')
       .append('h1')
       .text('Hello World!');
</script>


<script src="http://SPaddress/testingSubSite/D3docLib/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
     d3.select('body')
       .append('h1')
       .text('Hello World!');
</script>
```

Comment: you can ignore `html`, `head` and `body` tags. Run your code after document ready.

Comment: @AtishDipongkor so just the bit in between the <script> tags?

Comment: yes I mean it. see my answer.

Comment: Use `https` instead of `http`. You need `https` if you want to use cdn

Comment: @AtishDipongkor our sharepoint is on prem - so I don't think cdn is relevent.

Comment: what's your SP using? `http` or `https`? If your SharePoint site is in http, https cdn link won't work. In that case, download d3.js and upload it into a SharePoint libray and then give the script reference from SharePoint library

Comment: @AtishDipongkor http .... on prem. Do I need to be admin to upload into a library? Can I just upload to a bog standard Document Library?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46244/discussion-between-atish-dipongkor-and-whytheq).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem in loading script file(d3.v3.min.js). Everything is correct but the problem here is selecting 'body' will take the 'body' tag of the page, not the content editor web part tags.

[image: 'span' appended inside 'body' tag]

Replace the script:

```
<script>
d3.select(".ms-WPBody div.ms-rtestate-field").append("span")
    .text("Hello, world!");
</script>
```

Comment: did you load `d3.v3.min.js` into a doc library or just leave as a url to the D3 website reference? Did you test via an on premises version of sharepoint? Can you please add the section of the script which references `d3.v3.min.js`  ... obviously you need to anonymise but just to give me an idea of the exact form used for `src="http://SPaddress/testingSubSite/D3docLib/d3.v4.min.js"`

Comment: I just left the URL as the d3 website reference and I have tested in on premise version of sharepoint. (<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>)

Comment: this information is what has made the difference - `".ms-WPBody div.ms-rtestate-field"`. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in the `src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"`. It will be `https` instead of `http`.

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    (function() {
        d3.select('body')
            .append('h1')
            .text('Hello World!');
    })();
</script>
```

You can ignore `html`, `head` and `body` tags in CEWP. See demo [here](https://jsbin.com/legahukuxo/edit?html,js,console,output).

If your SharePoint site is in `http`, `https` cdn link won't work. In that case, download d3.js and upload it into a SharePoint libray and then give the script reference from SharePoint library.

```
<script src="{path of your SharePoint library}/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    (function() {
        d3.select('body')
            .append('h1')
            .text('Hello World!');
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: I am in Edit Page  ... in the Page Content there is a Script Editor > I have copied in your script > then check it back in BUT still an empty page!

Comment: Can you show me the errors from console?

Comment: Hi Atish - I've amended the question with what I've now tried